# Primary record selector from many records

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Say you have two tables:  Contacts and Orders.  One Contact can have many Orders, an order must always have a contact related to it.

There are two ways to add an order:

1. Go to the contacts tab, search for the contact you want, then go to the details page of that contact. On the details page, click 'Place Order.'  A new order will open with this contact already related to it - pretty easy.
2. Go to the orders tab and click 'New Order.'  A new order page will open - to relate a contact to this order I have a collection_select control in place which gets Contacts.all for the user to select one.

Option one is just fine, it works perfectly.  However, option two works fine until you get more than, say, 100 contacts.  Then, you just can't find the contact you want.

Just to make sure everyone understands the problem, lets take option two past just a few hundred contacts.  Lets say I have 50,000 contacts in my database.  Now a basic collection_select is not even an option - it just isn't.

I am looking for a text_field control which will allow you to type a name in, and it searches the database using ajax and lists the matching contacts below.  When I choose a contact, it will relate that contact to the order.

37signals.com uses a control like this in it's products.  Many other web companies do too.  Is there a plugin like this on github.com or something?  Where can I find this?  What should I even search for?

PS - as I am finishing adding this question I went to add a 'Tag' to the question.  As I type into this box a list of matching records drop down for me to select.  This is very similar to what I need!  Any ideas?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really like [Flexbox](http://www.fairwaytech.com/flexbox). It's a jQuery plugin. Very customizable, easy to configure and supports lots of stuff - AJAX calls included. Check out the demos and see if it fits your needs.

Comment: Wow - Flexbox looks really nice!  It even supports paging!  Thanks for the info ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this may be of use to you: [jQuery UI AutoComplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/). This can load data from a remote source using an AJAX call and display a limited set of results relating to the values entered in a text field, much like the tags box does on SO.

Comment: Thanks, I now know what this type of control is called.  I'm checking out the jQuery AutoComplete and Flexbox plugin.  I appreciate your help!